# How to write nested where condition with left join using npm Sequqlize

Tags: npm, sequelize.js

I am trying to implement left join query by clubbing

```
select product.* from products
left outer join cart as c on c.prodId = product.prodId 
left outer join order as order on c.cid = p.pid
where product.secondaryId = 10 and c.cpid = 210;
```

How can I write, Sequelize code for this.

**EDIT:**

**Here is the actual MYSQL query, what I am implementing to:**

```
select products.* from products
left outer join Cart as cart on cart.CartId = products.CartId 
left outer join Orders as order on order.OrderId = cart.PartId
where cart.CartId = 1 and order.CustId = 12;
```

**Association at Sequelize end**

```
Cart.hasMany(models.Products, {as: 'Products', foreignKey: 'CartId'})
Cart.belongsTo(models.Orders, { as: 'Orders', foreignKey: 'PartId'})

Products.belongsTo(models.Cart, {onDelete: "CASCADE", foreignKey: { name: 'CartId', allowNull: false})

Products -> PrimaryKey: ProduceId

Cart -> PrimaryKey: CartId

Orders -> PrimaryKey: OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `left outer join cart as c on c.prodId = product.prodId` will work as a usual join because of `c.cpid = 210` condition. Either remove it or move it to `on` clause like this:

```
left outer join cart as c on c.prodId = product.prodId and c.cpid = 210
```

As of Sequelize query because you didn't show your model definitions and associations I'll try to guess and write like this (so you can get the whole idea):

```
const products = await db.Products.findAll({
  where: {
    secondaryId: 10
  },
  include: [{
    model: db.Cart,
    required: false, // this is LEFT OUTER JOIN
    where: {
      cpid: 210
    },
    include: [{
      model: db.Order,
      as: 'Orders',
      required: false // this is LEFT OUTER JOIN
    }]
  }]
})
```

If you indicate your model definitions and associations then I can correct my answer as well (if necessary).

Comment: I simply added an alias for `Order` in the query. That's all that needed according to youe model definitions and associations